# Display each key type

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to decode this program. It is supposed to show each key that the user types. I keep getting multiple errors. Especially this error ::

> FixDebugFifteen3 is not abstract and does not override abstract method `keyPressed(KeyEvent)` in `KeyListener`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class FixDebugFifteen3 extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
  char key;

  Container con = null;
  GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(2, 1);
  JLabel label = new JLabel("Key Typed:");
  JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(4, 25);
  public FixDebugFifteen3()
  {
     setTitle("Debug Key Frame");
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     con = this.getcontentPanel();
     con.setLayout(grid);
     con.add(textArea);
     con.add(Label);
     addKeyListener(this);
     textArea.addKeyListener(this);
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
  {
     char c = Character.getKeyChar();
     label.setText ("Key Typed: " + c);
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
  {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     FixDebugFifteen3 kFrame = new DebugFifteen3();
     kFrame.setSize(300, 200);
     kFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are missing `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent) {}` method

Comment: Try using an IDE before you go just compiling some code. It'll highlight the errors.

Comment: You need to provide an implementation for `keyPressed` in your class, because your class implements the interface `KeyListener`.